# Pass Multiple addresses in redeem p2sh script

Tags: multi-signature, p2sh

I have the following code

```
const script = this.app.env.bitcoin.script.compile([
hashOpcode,
Buffer.from(secretHash, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUALVERIFY,

 Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
 this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL,
 this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_IF,

 Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
 this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKSIG
])
```

But i want to pass one more address. Like this:

```
Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL,
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_AND,
Buffer.from(exchangePublicKey, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL,
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_IF,

Buffer.from(recipientPublicKey, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKMULTISIG,
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_AND,
Buffer.from(exchangePublicKey, "hex"),
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_CHECKMULTISIG,
this.app.env.bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ELSE,
```

But its not working and i am getting only on 1 in txout. whats the correct way to add another multisig address ?

Just want to follow this pattern:

```
redeem script: 2 <pubKey1> <pubKey2> <pubKey3> 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Comment: in which project/library is this command defined? `this.app.env.bitcoin.script.compile`

Comment: Sorry for late reply
https://github.com/swaponline/swap.core/blob/9295ead434117c995c33976782aa2fac8361becf/src/swap.swaps/BtcSwap.js#L183